# How to load CSS into CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am totally new in CodeIgnitor. In the controllers folder I created a file named `caller.php` and I created a file `home.php` in views. In views I also created a folder named `css` and I created `style.css` in that `css` folder. In views I have some pictures. Those pictures are also part of design. Now I want to use `style.css` and the pictures. But I can't.

In caller.php I have:

```
class caller extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('home');  
        // What do I have to write here to load css?
    }
}
```

In home.php I have:

```
<html>
<head>

***------what i have to write here to load css--------***

</head>

<body>

<div id="outer">
...
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

If additional configs are needed please mention that.

Comment: Your main problem is the structure of your files. The css/ directory shouldn't be inside views/, it should be in a publicly accessible folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading on from what Oliver said of including the stylesheet with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
```

If you have removed index.php from your URL's make sure you include your css directory in the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is assuming your stylesheet is located in a folder called `css` at the root of your application.

```
- index.php
+ system
+ application
+ css
   - style.css
```

Make sure that you have enabled the URL helper to use commands such as [`base_url()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). This can be done globally inside [`config/autoload.php`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) by adding url to the helper array.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: what does it mean " removed index.php from your URL's ". can you explain.

Comment: yes my css file is located in the root directory in the folder called css

Comment: I don't know what actually rewrite rule is?

Comment: Have a read though the URL documentation http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html - It explains about it in there... If you've not done this then it should just work as oliver has explained.

Comment: when i write .... <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">  ... in home.php a blank page appears. when i don't link the style.css then  the page shown. Now what can i do?

Comment: It sounds like the URL helper isn't loaded. I have updated my answer explaining how to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
```

into home.php between `<head>` and `</head>` tags

and make sure the style.css is in a css folder in the main directory

Comment: what do you mean by main directory

Comment: in the same directory as the application folder, system folder, make a new one called css and place your stylesheet in there

Comment: when i load it a blank page appears.

Comment: when i write .... <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css"> ... in home.php a blank page appears. when i don't link the style.css then the page shown. Now what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @ Malachi. `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` is my file path & not working.

I have used

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

on my .htaccess file & it's working now smoothly. assets is my file file path

Comment: You should keep your assets or css/js file on root directory of CI.